# I'm storing axios response into two different "data" variables, if I change one variable it will automatically changes other variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In the below html code , I'm simply iterating through 2 variables posts and cp_posts:

**HTML CODE**

```
  <div v-if="loading">
    loading...
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <p style="background:#ebebeb" v-for="post in posts">
      {{post}}
    </p>

    <p style="background:#ebaaeb" v-for="post in cp_posts">
      {{post}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the below Vue script, I'm making one axios call to demo URL for fetching some dummy data. Once the request is done I'm storing response data into locally defined variable i.e **temp**, after that I'm assigning *temp* to Vue data variables **posts** and **cp_posts**.

After assignment I'm changing **posts** variable, that's it.

```
const URL = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
    return {
        loading: true,
      posts: [], // add posts here so reactivity is working, also undefined would be OK
      cp_posts: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    //this.loading = true --> not needed already set in data
    axios.get(URL).then((response) => {
        // console.log(response.data, this)
      var temp = response.data.data
      this.posts = temp
      this.cp_posts = temp

      this.posts[0].id = 4444 // <== Here I'm changing value from posts variable which will change cp_posts
      this.loading = false
    })
  }
})
```

**OUTPUT**

You can see **cp_posts** variable ==> id: 4444 also get changes, which should be 1, because I haven't touch **cp_posts** variable in above code

variable : *posts*

```
{ "id": 4444, "first_name": "George", "last_name": "Bluth", "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg" }

{ "id": 2, "first_name": "Janet", "last_name": "Weaver", "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg" }

{ "id": 3, "first_name": "Emma", "last_name": "Wong", "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg" }
```

variable : *cp_posts*

```
{ "id": 4444, "first_name": "George", "last_name": "Bluth", "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg" }

{ "id": 2, "first_name": "Janet", "last_name": "Weaver", "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg" }

{ "id": 3, "first_name": "Emma", "last_name": "Wong", "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg" }
```

Why **cp_post** variable also get changes while changing **post** variable?

Ref Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/LokeshKhandare/31zvmcwp/2/

Comment: because both are the same object, as you assign the same object (temp) to both properties

Comment: Both `this.posts` and `this.cp_posts` refer to the same object. That's how Javascript (and most other programming languages) work. It's not related to Vue.js or Axios. Google *value vs reference semantics* on Google and read it, e.g. [Explaining Values vs. Reference in Javascript](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0). A solution could be to make a deep copy of the object. In Javascript it's often done by converting the object to a JSON string and then parsing it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `posts` and `cp_posts`, they have the reference of `temp` that make it mutable. 
So what you can do is you can change  this line

`this.cp_posts=temp`

to

`this.cp_posts=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp))`

This will solve your problem. [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/m9fpd1v3/)

Comment: Hey Niraj! Thank you so much. I appreciate the solution you have shared on JSFiddle.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `cp_posts` is also changed is that in JS `arrays` and `objects` are ***reference type*** values which means they reference to address of the value in Memory. If you change the value they all changes. One way I found to solve is from this [medium post](https://medium.com/@gamshan001/javascript-deep-copy-for-array-and-object-97e3d4bc401a):

```js
    //Deep Clone
    let a = [{ x:{z:1} , y: 2}];
    let b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
    b[0].x.z=0
    console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); //[{"x":{"z":1},"y":2}]
    console.log(JSON.stringify(b)); // [{"x":{"z":0},"y":2}]
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much. The article you have shared regarding "Deep copy" was really helpful. I appreciate the solution, it worked for me, once again thanks a lot.

Comment: If that helped you , there is an option to *upvote* the answer